# meaning of referendum

Tags: meaning

> 'Referendum' is the gerund of the Latin verb refero, and has the meaning 'bringing back' (i.e. bringing the question back to the people).
>
> [wikipedia.org: Referendum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referendum)

Wiki says Referendum is bringing the question(vote) back to the People.
I think it implies vote is moved in this sequence : people->government->People.

But actually the pieces of vote paper moves in reverse : government->people-> government. therefore I conclude the Statement should be modified like this
bring the question back to the government

What do you think?

Comment: Where exactly does Wiki say that? You need to provide more context. In any case this is probably a question which belongs more on the Politics site.

Comment: First, this is not a place to ask for opinions. Otherwise, you kind of figured it out, didn't you? The people elect the government, the government gives an important decision back to the people. This is when a referendum happens. How the piece of paper moves is of no importance for the referendum, government could theoretically have a company hand out the papers or whatever. The vote (as wikipedia says) is given back to the people.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is incoherent.  A referendum is a vote on an issue submitted to the population.  It may be on an issue that a legislature has also voted on.  Or not.

Comment: It may be a question better asked on the "politics" site.

Comment: Assuming you mean [wikipedia.org: Referendum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referendum) the best place to discuss this is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Referendum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question refers to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referendum), which states:

> "'Referendum' is the gerund of the Latin verb refero, and has the
>   meaning 'bringing back' (i.e. bringing the question back to the
>   people). "

The question is therefore not so much about what a referendum *is*, but rather whether its etymology accurately reflects its current *usage*.

As the Wikipedia page notes, the way a referendum is used varies from country to country, but in all cases the common element is that the parliament takes a question and puts it to the people, who then vote on the matter. There can be no doubt, therefore, that etymology does indeed reflect current usage.

Where practice differs between jurisdictions is in what power is given to that vote. In some cases, the vote may directly cause a new law or constitutional amendment to be adopted; in other cases, a referendum is simply a **straw vote**, giving guidance to the parliament on how to deal with the question but not binding the parliament to act accordingly.